# How to manage CSS Libraries in the front end?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-frontend

With node and browserify it's easy to manage js dependencies by just buttoning it all up into a bundle.js file  and including that in the parent html.

What I'm wondering is how do you guys manage libs like bootstrap?

They download just fine to node_modules but how do you get them into your html files or asset folder?

Do you just reference them straight from node_modules?  Have a task copy them in?  Etc?

Caveat, I was hoping to do this without the browserify-css plugin because I want to keep my css and js separate.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have a Gulp / Grunt workflow setup in which I included my js/css modules and then it automatically do all the important task and at the end I have only one css and js file. Then I import them to HTML.

I suggest you to make task for gulp or grunt which will check for changes in the folder that you decide ( where download of libraries will be ). If there is a change - it will automatically copy the .css files into another working directory.

I hope I understand what you want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a little python script that allows me to import files(.js, .css, .younameit) from a directory to the html.

before:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- {SVN_AUTO_IMPORT type:.js; dir:../tsc_out; exclude:; template:<script src="%PATH"</script>;} -->
    </head>
```

after:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="../tsc_out/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script3.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script4.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script5.js"></script>
  </head>
```

https://github.com/seven-jerry/html-importer